# Need help condensing code my code for JavaScript which is in a function

Tags: javascript

Basically, I am trying to create paws for an animal and I was wondering how I would condense my code. The code creates a line that moves after it is done moving forward 15 spaces. It is already in a function. I can only use this variable:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

}
```

and this function:

```
function myFunction() {

}
```

```
function drawHands () {
  penUp();
  moveTo(215, 280);
  penColor("black");
  penDown();
  penWidth(3);
  turnTo(0);
  moveForward(15);
  penUp();
  moveTo(230, 280);
  penDown();
  moveForward(15);
  penUp();
  moveTo(265, 280);
  penDown();
  moveForward(15);
  penUp();
  moveTo(280, 280);
  penDown();
  moveForward(15);
}
drawHands();
```

Comment: Hello there! I believe we can add more tags here and be more specific. Is this turtle.js? The functions `penUp`, `penDown`, etc., does not belong to JavaScript, so you must be using some libraries here. Can you add it in your tags?

Answer (score 1):

You have some similar repeated functionality: inside `drawHands`, you frequently call `penUp`, then `moveTo`, then `penDown`, then `moveForward`. So, you can put all of that into a function, and then call that function inside `drawHands` instead:

```
const upMoveDownLength = (x, y, length) => {
  penUp();
  moveTo(x, y);
  penDown();
  moveForward(length);
};
function drawHands () {
  penColor("black");
  penWidth(3);
  turnTo(0);
  upMoveDownLength(215, 280, 15);
  upMoveDownLength(230, 280, 15);
  upMoveDownLength(265, 280, 15);
  upMoveDownLength(280, 280, 15);
}
```

If the parameter passed to `moveForward` is always going to be 15, then `upMoveDownLength` doesn't need a 3rd parameter, and you can hard-code `moveForward(15);` instead of `moveForward(length);`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using **exactly** the for loop and function as described

```
function myFunction() {
  penUp();
  moveTo(+arguments[1], 280);
  if (+arguments[0] === 0) {
    penColor("black");
  }
  penDown();
  if (+arguments[0] === 0) {
    penWidth(3);
    turnTo(0);
  }
  moveForward(15);
}

function drawHands () {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    myFunction(i, [215, 230, 265, 280][i])
  }
}
drawHands();
```

This can be simplified if the penColor, penWidth and turnTo can be set before the first "move"

```
function myFunction() {
  penUp();
  moveTo(+arguments[0], 280);
  penDown();
  moveForward(15);
}

function drawHands () {
  penColor("black");
  penWidth(3);
  turnTo(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    myFunction([215, 230, 265, 280][i])
  }
}
drawHands();
```

`myFunction([215, 230, 265, 280][i])` calls `myFuction` with the i'th value in the inline Array ... so, 215, 230 etc

now, since `myFunction`, as described by you can not have formal arguments, the code uses the functions `arguments` "property" to retrieve the argument(s) ... the unary `+` coerces the value to be a Number